# Can't change the stroke width for a symbol object in inkscape

Tags: inkscape, stroke

I have inserted a flowchart object using: `Object -> Symbol`. I can not change the stroke width as I usually do from the `fill and stroke`. Even when I try to make the stroke width to 0, it has not effect in that symbol. The problem is illustrated here:

[image]

Comment: If it's anything like Illustrator's symbols, then the appearance is part of the symbol and can't be edited on an individual basis.  You'll need to edit the original symbol or "break link to symbol" as Illustrator calls it, to convert the symbol into a regular (editable) object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symbols behave much like clones, so their properties come from the original object. I'm assuming you don't want to edit the original, just this particular instance. Therefore, click your symbol once to select, then go to **Edit / Clone / Unlink Clone** (or Shift + Alt + D). That changes it to a regular Inkscape object with nodes, and you can change stroke width, colour etc.

Comment: I added a math symbol (square root) with Unicode `U+221A`. I followed your suggestion but it has `Style Stroke` option disabled (grayed out). Any suggestions?